# Optimize mysql/JS/php chat

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, optimization, chat

I made this javascript/php/mysql, 2 users, chat. Every 3 seconds it request (ajax) the php file with the messagges and update the page. The php query the database with:

```
SELECT * FROM tmessagges WHERE author='Jack' OR author='John'
```

Can I optimize this ?

The first thing that I think to optimize is all the requests wasted when thare are no new messagges, but im not sure if worth it...
May be selecting just id or counting, and make a second request only when there are new messagges.

```
SELECT id FROM tmessagges WHERE author='Jack' OR author='John'
```

or

```
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM tmessagges WHERE author='Jack' OR author='John'
```

then the first query, if new messagges.

worth it ? cos the cpu usage is about the same I think, just less traffic...

OR other ways to optimize ?

Comment: Optimize...how? What are you trying to achieve? Less lag? More throughput? Less DB overhead? More ops per second? Higher resolution? Less calories? None of these? More than one of these?

Comment: I think traffic, server cpu/memory, db traffic. A query every 3 seconds seems expensive to me... I have yet to test it in the real server, meanwhile if its optimizable...

Comment: You might be trying to over-optimise, prematurely. If you have a bottleneck, get some data. Use a profiling tool such as xhprof or xdebug's profile mode. On the flip side, ensure you have the right indexes in the database and your queries will be speedy :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a sequence number associated with each message, then ask for only messages "later" than that number.

Have only one "name" to look for -- perhaps a "message ID", not "Jack" OR "John".

Now the query is shorter:

```
SELECT * FROM Messages WHERE seq > 12345 AND msg_id = 199;
```

And that will usually return nothing other than some kind of "empty" reply.  When there is a message, it will return only the new message(s), not the rest of the conversation.

Furthermore, don't send the SQL across the wire.  Instead have some kind of protocol that minimizes traffic such as

```
"new;12345;199"
```

Comment: Good one! a double optimization! Thanks. (i'll wait a little to accept)

Comment: question: what's better between `SELECT COUNT(id) FROM tmessagges WHERE author='Jack' OR author='John'` and `SELECT id FROM tmessagges WHERE author='Jack' OR author='John' LIMIT 1` (that is your suggestion i think) ??? Both queries return just one number, so the traffic is optimized. But COUNT will browse all the rows, and LIMIT 1 no ? there is also a cpu optimization using LIMIT ???

Comment: If there could be multiple messages, then `COUNT(id)` (or simply `COUNT(*)`) has to go through them to count them; this is worse than with `LIMIT 1` (or `EXISTS)`, which need find one, then quit.